# Kivy Pop Up scale issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I have this custom popup compoenent in kivy. When I scale it down to 0.5, the pop up is scaled down pefectly with all the internal components. but there is a transparent background and the buttons are not clickale on their visible position. Buttons are clickable on the original position. Here is the code:

```
<CustomPopup@Popup>:
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Scale:
            x: 0.5
            y: 0.5
            z: 0.5
            origin: self.center
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
    id: configure_popup
    title: "Configure Server Settings"  # Title of the popup
    size_hint: None, None
    size: dp(600), dp(320)  # Set the size of the popup
    
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1  # Two columns for labels and text inputs
        padding: dp(10)
        spacing: dp(10)
        
        TextInput:
            id: server_url  # Reference to the first text input
            hint_text: 'Server URL'
            multiline: True  # Allow only single-line input
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(40)

        TextInput:
            id: api_key  # Reference to the second text input
            hint_text: 'Api Key'
            multiline: False  # Allow only single-line input
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(40)

        Label:
            text: "Keep this key secret: it provides access to all your data. You can get this key on your profile on the webapp"  # Text for the label
            color: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1  # Set text color to grey
            italic: True  # Make the text italic
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]  # Adjust the height based on the text size
            text_size: self.width, None 

        Button:
            text: "Save and close window"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(40)
            on_release: configure_popup.save_and_close()
        
        Button:
            id: test_conifg_button
            text: "Test Server Configuration"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(40)
            on_release: app.test_server_configuration(server_url.text, api_key.text, self)
```

How can i go about this issue? any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `canvas` instructions in your code only affect how your `CustomPopup` is drawn. The actual properties (like `pos` and `size`) that motion events rely on, are not changed, so those events will still act the same as without the `canvas` instructions. So, basically, you are creating a `Button` in one position, but drawing it in a different position. And that drawing does not affect the actual functioning of the `Button`. A better approach would be to define the contents of the `CustomPopup` using things like `size_hint` and `pos_hint`, so that the actual `pos` and `size` of the widgets will adjust to the size of the `CustomPopup`.

Comment: I tried using size hint for the contents of the pop up but the behavior is still same.

Comment: You must also remove the canvas instructions, and adjust the size of the `CustomPopup` using `size` or `size_hint`.

Comment: actually the reason i am scaling down is because I want it to be usable with 300x scaling on windows. Your suggestion works perfectly on any resolution as long as the scaling is fine but the scaling messes up the whole layout